# GenghisApp - restrict access from public and have access only for me as a admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, vps

I have installed on my VPS the [Genghis Admin](http://genghisapp.com/)  for MongoDB administration. I use only "gem install genghisapp" a running app with "genghisapp -L".

Is there any way how can I restrict access from public and have access only for me as a admin?

Now everyone has access to my genghisapp, but it shows "Connection error: unauthorized" next to my server name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the Genghis App from within another Rails app and then bootstrap Devise to handle authentication for you.

```
mount Genghis::Server.new, :at => '/genghis'
```

Then with Devise, do

```
authenticated :user do
   mount Genghis::Server.new, :at => '/genghis'
end
```

...and only authenticated users can access '/genghis'.  You could implement a feature to log details of all the users that visited this route (activity tracking) and receive daily-digest by email if you're concerned about any authenticated users as well; then there's authorisation that could even be added on top ~ see the CanCan gem for that.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's right if you already have a Rails app you want to integrate with. It has the added benefit of not requiring a separate process to run Genghis, since it's mounted on a path of your actual Rails app.

If not, you could use Rack with basic auth and a super simple config:

```
require 'genghis'
use Rack::Auth::Basic, 'Genghis' { |u, p| u == 'admin' && p == 'hunter2' }
run Genghis::Server
```

Swap out 'admin' and 'hunter2' for your preferred auth, then run via `rackup` instead of `genghisapp -L`.